# Expression of HelperResult to format item from a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm doing a component to format a list, it is an Extension, I wrote the following code, but, when in execution time, it gives me the error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult' because it is not a delegate type

This is the extension:

```
public static MvcHtmlString FormatMyList<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, IEnumerable<TValue> list,
            Expression<Func<TValue, System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult>> formatExp = null)
        {

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var itemFormated = formatExp.Compile().Invoke(item).ToString();
            }

            return new MvcHtmlString("");
        }
```

View calling:

```
var test = Html.FormatMyList<ModelType, ListType>(list, formatExp:
        x =>
            @<text>
                This is format of @x.Cambio to test @x.Fala
            </text>);
```

I already tried to change from HelperResult to dynamic, but didn't work too.

I don't want to use only `Func<object, HelperResult>` as suggested in some posts in StackOverFlow, because, there will be items inside the `<text></text>`, that needs to be strongly typed as an item of ListType.

The format can be different in my views, so I can't use a template to ListType.

Is there a way to do that, even that not using the expression?

Thanks

Comment: You marked `FormatMyList()` as an extension method, but you're not calling it on any object. Instead, you're using it as a static method, which means you're missing one of the parameters.

Comment: You pass `formatExp` not as `Expression` but as `Func` already.

Comment: It's an extension from HtmlHelper, in the piece of code of view, you can see: Htm.FormatMyList. Html in this context it's a HtmlHelper.

Comment: Change signature of `formatExp` to `Func<TValue, System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, instead of use an expression `Expression<Func<TValue, System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult>>`, I used only a Func:

```
Func<TValue, System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult>
```

View:

```
var test = Html.FormatMyList<ModelType, ListType>(list, format:
        @<text>
                This is format of @item.Cambio to test @item.Fala
            </text>);
```

I used the "item" key to access the LisType properties.

The unique reason to use an expression, was to access the properties strongly typed, as I can use the "item" key, I don't need a Expression anymore.

It works to me, thanks.